# How to split dynamic array and apply them into table

Tags: php, arrays

Need help, Myscript generate dynamic array and the output is such like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => A, B, C, D  
    [1] => 15,20,24,19
    [2] => X,Y,Z,W
)
```

or

```
Array
(
    [0] => A, B, C, D
    [1] => 15,20,24,19
)
```

where is sometime 2 main index or more.

How to apply them into HTML table, so the result will be like this :

```
------------------
Field 1 | Field 2 |
------------------
A       | 15      |
------------------
B       | 20      |
------------------
C       | 24      |
------------------
D       | 19      |
------------------
```

Where the fields are follow number of main index.

Great Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are comma delimited strings, then you need to map those first and explode. Then you can continue on to group them and line them up so that they could be easier to just loop. Example:

```
$array = ['A,B,C,D', '15,20,24,19', 'X,Y,Z,W'];
// explode comma delimited
$pieces = array_map(function($piece){
    return explode(',', $piece);
}, $array);
// group them
$group = array(); $i = 0;
while(true) {
    foreach ($pieces as &$piece) {
        $group[$i][] = array_shift($piece);
    }
    $i++;
    $last = end($pieces);
    if(empty($last)) break;
}
// then just echo them in a table
echo '<table cellpadding="10">';
echo '<tr>';
for($x = 1, $size = count($array); $x <= $size; $x++) echo '<td>Field ' . $x . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($group as $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $v) {
        echo '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

[Sample Out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oJYEc1)

Comment: One small thing, in your `for` action you keep counting the length of the same unchanged `array $array`. Better put this value in a `variable` and reuse it.

Comment: @RST sure no prob, easy to revise anyways

Answer (score 0):

After calling `explode()` on each subarray of strings, you will not need to run any further preparations, just access the column data using `array_column()`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d1360fe69a571f7b06120be0c9e9a8f8de07cc8))

```
$array=['A, B, C, D', '15,20,24,19', 'X,Y,Z,W'];  // differing delimiters: comma vs comma-space
$array=array_map(function($s){return preg_split('/, ?/',$s);},$array);

echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        for($x=1,$column_count=sizeof($array); $x<=$column_count; ++$x){
            echo "<th>Field$x</th>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($array[0] as $i=>$v){
        echo "<tr><td>",implode("</td><td>",array_column($array,$i)),"</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Field1</th><th>Field2</th><th>Field3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td><td>15</td><td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td><td>20</td><td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td><td>24</td><td>Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td><td>19</td><td>W</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```